# Resizing and compressing the image which am getting from url

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage

In my project am trying to compressing the images (coming from the server).I used HJManager for compressing. In  that they are compressing the uiimage to user mentioned size, thats cool but taking too much of app memory.For 30 images it is taking almost 400 mb of live bytes. and its getting crashing. If you want to see my code, i'll paste it. But i want to know the best way to compress(mbs to kbs) the image which am getting from the server without disturbing the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Much better caching library with smaller memory footprint than HJManager and more modern, it uses blocks with completion handler. Last but not least, it is actively maintained which means that even if there is an issue, the community patches it.

You can resize the image easily with a method like this:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

Comment: yeah ur right, but it is not resizing the uiimage,, I tried this SDWebImage, its quite gud compare to HJ but it is streching out my image. So,i want to resize the image exactly to the original image size with less quality.

Comment: it is streching my image niko. I cant use that

Comment: add this to your imageView so the image does not strech: `myimageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`